# В React.js 15.5.4 не могу импортировать browserHistory

Tags: reactjs

Сильно не пинайте я только начал постигать React делаю по видео урокам. Они конечно немного устарели. 
Проблема такая как в React.js 15.5.4 импортировать browserHistory или hashHistory из react-router 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***React Router v4*** — это переработанный вариант популярного React дополнения. Зависимые от платформы конфигурации роутов из прошлой версии были удалены и теперь всё является простыми компонентами. 
вот на хабре появилась [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/329996/)

Answer (score 1):

browserHistory нет в react. Он есть в react-router. В текущей версии v4 нельзя просто так вытащить history. Там другие методы через withRouter... https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

Либо поставьте react-router@2.8.1

Comment: да я и имел виду react-router 4